# Remove object if its id number is present

Tags: python

I have a Python file that format multiple objects in a JSON array (10 000). When this is done, I dump all in a new JSON file. 
Bu I'd like to write a file with only 50 of the objects, based on ids. When this will be done, I'll write objects in a demo-file.

```
with open('./output/' + datefile + 'complete_format-test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_output:
  json.dump(data, json_output, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

  for i in data:
        demoID= {[10202, 10300, 10615, 10890, 11161, 11204, 11460, 12043, 12054, 12617, 12633, 12736, 13689, 13730, 13755, 13764, 13894, 14472, 14837, 15328, 15383, 15403, 15449, 15771,
                 16121, 16134, 16205, 16242, 16434, 16485, 16487, 16622, 17769, 18001, 18074, 18673, 18689, 18762, 18863, 18912, 19243, 19478, 19758, 19895, 20299, 20981, 21010, 21064, 21078]}

        if not demoID in i["objectID"]:
            del(i)
            print(i)
```

Sample of the JSON:

```
  [{
    "objectID": 21064,
    "cars_getroute": "volkswagen-typ",
  },
  {
    "objectID": 21078,
    "cars_getroute": "volvo-123",
  } ...
]
```

So if a objectID is in the demoID list, I keep it and remove the others.
At the moment, I have a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define `demoID` as a `set`, without the inner `[]`,

then you can filter out the correct data like this:

```py
data = [
    {
        "objectID": 21064,
        "cars_getroute": "volkswagen-typ",
    },
    {
        "objectID": 999,
        "cars_getroute": "999",
    },
    {
        "objectID": 21078,
        "cars_getroute": "volvo-123",
    },
]

demoID = {
    10202, 10300, 10615, 10890, 11161, 11204, 11460, 12043, 12054, 12617, 12633, 12736, 13689, 13730, 13755, 13764,
    13894, 14472, 14837, 15328, 15383, 15403, 15449, 15771,
    16121, 16134, 16205, 16242, 16434, 16485, 16487, 16622, 17769, 18001, 18074, 18673, 18689, 18762, 18863, 18912,
    19243, 19478, 19758, 19895, 20299, 20981, 21010, 21064, 21078}

data = [d for d in data if d["objectID"] in demoID]

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you but if I use `del(data)` the console returns `data is not defined`

Comment: this solution doesn't require using `del` at all, it should replace the entire for-loop.

Comment: @QBolgi  `data` after this line should not contain any of the bad elements

Comment: No it doens't, it prints all the objects.

Comment: @QBolgi maybe your data is a little different from what you described in your example? try running my edited answer and see...

Comment: Maybe that's because I work with the file before what I send and then there is a conflict with `data`. I'm going to check.

Comment: perhaps the condition in the comprehension should be `d['objectID'] in demoID`, based on the names being used.

Comment: Yep that was it, tank you !

Comment: @QBolgi awesome, I'll edit my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

There error you observe is related to how you are defining `demoID`.
Basically:

```
x = {[1, 2, 3]}
```

tries to generate a `set()` whose one and only element is the list `[1, 2, 3]`.
However, it is not possible to use `list`s as elements for sets because they are not *hashable*. This is basically what that error is telling you.

However, there are a number of additional shortcomings to your code:

1. `demoID` is defined inside a loop for no particularly good reason and gets wastefully recomputed every time;
2. you try to modify `data` (with `del`) while it is being looped through. This may cause your container to get to inconsistent behavior and should be avoided;
3. you try to use `i` (with `print`) after it is deleted;
4. the condition of your loop `not demoID in i["objectID"]` is unnatural and unlikely what you would like to do: `demoID` is a container and `i["objectID"]` an element, and they should probably be inverted, e.g. `i["objectID"] in demoID`;
5. you say that you want to limit your *result* to some 50 entries, but this it not enforced anywhere in the code. Perhaps this is relying on the assumption that your `"objectID"` is unique and that the length of `demoID` is 50, but you may want to do this more explicitly.

---

Given this and that I have no access to your data, I will write some code working on some test data that does not have those shortcomings and should be easily applicable to your case:

```py
import random
import string

random.seed(0)

# generate dummy data
num = 10000
source_data = [
    {'objectID': random.randint(1, num),
     'cars_getroute': string.ascii_letters[0:random.randint(1, 50)]}
    for _ in range(num)]

print(len(source_data))
# 10000
```

Now assume you want to restrict (*filter*) `source_data` to have only `objectID` as specified in `demoID`. The standard approach is to generate a new container with only the *filtered* elements:

```py
# generate dummy `demoID`
# here we are using a `set()` which is a sensible choice, given the expected usage,
# but we could have used e.g. a list or a tuple
demoID = {random.randint(1, num) for _ in range(50)}

# filter-out `source_data`
data = [
    elem
    for elem in source_data
    if elem['objectID'] in demoID]

# output could be different depending on the random seed
# in general, it is not `50` due to possible duplicates
# in both `demoID` and `source_data['objectID']`
print(len(data))
# 51
```

If you now want to actively restrict the number to say `50` maximum, you should *slice* your data, i.e.:

```py
max_num = 50
demo_data = data[:max_num]

# could be less if `data` has less than `max_num` items
print(len(data[:max_num]))
# 50
```

(EDIT: Note that @Adam.Er8's answer uses the same approach proposed here)

---

## EDIT 2

If you really want to modify `source_data`, the common approach is to get the index of the list elements you want to remove in a first loop and remove it in a second loop (after sorting the indexes from larger to smaller, so that when removing items it does not invalidate the index values previously computed), e.g.

```py
# note that the condition here is the negation of
# what is used with the *filter* approach
to_remove = [
     i
     for i, elem in enumerate(source_data)
     if not elem['objectID'] in demoID]

for i in sorted(to_remove, reverse=True):
    source_data.pop(i)
    
print(len(source_data))
# 51
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete answer !